# JavaScript fails after ajax load

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I'm using this JavaScript:

```
var text = document.querySelector('._3672');
text.addEventListener('keydown', grow);
```

but it stops working after I load new content with ajax.

Is it possible to put all my JavaScript content inside a variable like this:

```
var init = {
    grow: function() {
        var text = document.querySelector('._3672');
        text.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    }
}
```

I don't want use JQuery's `.on()`

Comment: What is the value of `event` and `handler`? They are undefined in your snippet.

Comment: jQuery `.on` is designed to solve exactly this problem.  Is there a reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: Did you checked the console for any javascript error ?

Comment: it is working at console

Comment: When you load new content you need to bind your event handlers to that content.  Either that or bind your event handlers to common parent elements which don't change during the life of the DOM and respond to the propagated events.

Comment: If your HTML changes, you'll *either* need to re-attach the handlers *or* attach on a higher level in your HTML that doesn't change. It'd be easier for us to recommend one over the other if you share the relevant HTML too.